# cPanel file permissions for PHP includes

Tags: php, cpanel

I'm new to coding and for one of my new project, I have `html` files inside a folder names includes in my cpanel. There are my `nav` and `footer`.

I use `<?php include 'footer.php';?>` tags to import them in to my documents.

I'm worried that Google might index these files in my `includes` folder. I want to know what is the correct permission set for this folder or if theres are better way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add robots.txt file in which you can mention which folder should be readable or which is not.

Comment: Do you have access to the folder containing the document root? The best practice is to put folders like `includes` outside of the document root of the server, so that the pubic can't access them, but the server still can.

Comment: Yes I do have access.

Comment: Then you should definitely do that. You should still be able to access the files in your PHP code.

Comment: Thanks for this. I consider this as an answer. So that means I have to move my includes folder to a sub folder right? like instead of includes/footer.html .. I use like myfolder/includes/footer.html.

Comment: No, not a subfolder. If your index.php is in /path/to/mysite then you don't want your includes anywhere under /path/to/mysite. You can put them in /path/to/includes for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice to solve problems like this: Secure your PHP code(Or any other file that shouldn't be accessed by the public) by putting them outside of the public server document root.

Say for example you have a Apache server running at `/var/www/public`

And you have your `index.php` file for the homepage inside that directory alongside your `js`, `css` and `img` folders.

You should then put any files like `footer.php` or `header.php` (Or any Controllers or Models if you are using a MVC or OOP) in the `/var/www` folder.

This means that they will not be accessible to anyone visiting your website (They can't GET: footer.php).

Your PHP code inside `/var/www/public` should still be able to access the files inside `/var/www`.

It is the cleanest to (If you don't have it already) to create a `public` folder in `/var/www` and set the document root of the server to that.

Since you are using cPanel [here](https://www.servint.net/university/article/the-tech-bench-changing-a-document-root-in-cpanel/) is an example.

Your folder structure will look like this:

- var/www

  - includes

    - footer.php
  - public <-- server document root

    - css

      - style.css
    - js
    - img
    - index.php